# Docker private registry with TLS, can the private key be password protected?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-registry, tls1.3

I am setting up a docker registry container using the registry:2.8.1 image.
If I use a key and crt created without a password it works, but if I use a key and crt created with a key and crt with a password, the container barrel rolls, restarting with the error:

`level=fatal msg="tls: failed to parse private key"`

Going through the documentation, I see no option to pass a password into this when running the container.
I've seen a couple discussions from 2015 and 2017 similar to this, but the Docker registry documentation does not mention anything about this.

Right now it looks like you cannot use a private key generated with a password when setting up a registry with TLS, which I find surprising.
Could someone confirm if this is the case and possibly provide an explanation as to the reason?

Comment: This feels more appropriate as a GitHub issue with the specific project.